# Best way to manipulate Windows ACL permissions

Tags: c#, .net, security, permissions

My goal is to find out how to programmatically adjust permissions on files & directories in Windows using .NET.

I have identified the following options:

1. Windows API (yuck!)
2. [Active Directory Service Interfaces](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899553) (COM... ugh...)
3. Windows PowerShell (?)
4. Google for an easy-to-use facade.

None of these seem very palatable to me. Which route would you guys take? Perhaps there's another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this type of thing using the [FileSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity.aspx) class