# Prevent a program from being forcibly killed through taskmanager

Tags: c#

My program needs to be gracefully stopped or it can cause a lot of instabilities and possibly BSOD.

How do I prevent it from being closed through the task manager? If I remember correctly Norton does this.

Comment: I believe the cleanest, least intrusive way is to move the logic that needs a graceful shutdown to a Windows service.

Comment: Use two applications that constantly monitor the existence of the other application. If one is shutdown using task manager, other one can bring it up. Btw this information can be used in a lot of evil ways!!

Comment: @500-InternalServerError How do I do that?

Comment: @Abhinav Anything can be used for evil if you want.

Comment: Explaining that would be too long for this format. Do some googling.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Ok, thank you. I'll check into it.

Comment: @Abhinav Read this again `My program needs to be gracefully stopped or it can cause a lot of instabilities and possibly BSOD` How does using two apps help?

Comment: I don't believe you can prevent process being killed (other than by permissions manipulation), but look at `C` `signal()` about how to install a handler that would allow you to do cleanup and clean exit when process is terminated.

Comment: @LB2 Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278099/best-way-to-manipulate-windows-acl-permissions) what you're talking about?

Comment: @chipperyman573 Not quite - that article is about changing file permissions, and I was referring to process permissions.  What I meant there is that if process running under administrator account, then non-admins wouldn't have permissions to kill it AFAIK.  I think pushing process to run under system account further protects it, but wouldn't prevent another process under system account to kill it.  So it would help, but wouldn't solve completely.  I think "dying gracefully" when being killed is the way to solve your problem, albeit not simple one.

Comment: If Norton really "does this", it likely uses a kernel driver.  We're definitely not looking at C#-level solutions here.

Comment: @aleksey.berezan Yes, you're on the right track of what I meant.  C-style `signal()` call allows to intercept kill signal, and do some action before the process is killed.  That action could be shutting down gracefully so as not to leave the state corrupted.  Read MSDN article about [signal() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx).  .NET PInvoke interop for this one may get quite tricky.

Comment: What about creating c# watch-dog app, that watches for subscribes for target process "Exited" event and when the event gets fired - it does the job. Something like that: `Process p = Process.GetProcessById(processId:42); p.Exited += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("graceful hardcore cleanup");`  Any thoughts?

Comment: You can not prevent your programm from beeing shut down by the task manager when you are using .net. You can write a c-programm in kernel mode that could not be killed but this is something that drivers, Anti-Virus-Software and of course Viruses/malware do. This is nothing a normal programm should do.

Comment: @aleksey.berezan The problem is that it can't end at all or it will cause issues. The solution I decided to go with is let it end at any point so that it won't cause these issues.

Comment: @aleksey.berezan Exited event fires once process ends (naturally or killed), which is too late for OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with a normal executable. If you are that deep in the kernel that you can cause a BSOD, you should be writing a kernel driver (and certainly not C#).

From Raymond Chen:

> Programs can try to make themselves more difficult to kill (deny PROCESS_TERMINATE access, deny PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD access so people can't CreateRemoteThread(EndProcess), deny PROCESS_VM_WRITE so people can't scribble into your stack and make you doublefault, deny PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME so they can't suspend you), but eventually you just can't stop them from, say, elevating to Debug privilege, debugging your process, and moving EIP to "ExitProcess".